# HTML and PHP and the difference of using both

Tags: php, html

> is there's any  difference bewteen using html code  in php code or php code in html code ?Does it differ in the performance ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) might help.

Comment: I would encourage you to test this yourself. You know what you're talking about, which means you have examples of both. Simply test those to see which is the most performant, or if there is no difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no performance difference between using HTML in a PHP file and using PHP in an HTML file. It's more about structuring and organizing your code. Using PHP in HTML code allows for more dynamic content, whereas using HTML in PHP files allows for easier separation of the presentation layer and the application logic.